# Change default style of MS Access elements

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

When I add any element (control like text box, label etc) to my form, it has default style as:

Font: Calibri (Detail)
Font Size: 11
Fore Color: Text 2, Lighter 40%

How is it  possible to change that, I need MS Sans Serif, 8, Black for default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what version of Access you are using, but I'm sure the newer versions have similar features.  (I use 2003 because I hate having everything showing up in one scroll bar)

First Setup a Form, text box, and label to the settings you would like and save. (Background Colors as well).
Second Click AutoFormat button> Customize > Set Standard from the form and click OK.

Should do the trick.  AutoFormat Button looks like a Wand over piece of paper.

Comment: I need to do that for each new element I add to form

Answer (score 2):

In Access 2018 (though sure to change in the future) this is done by:

1. Select the object whose values you want to make default
2. In the "Design" tab, to the right of where you select a new control to add (text boxes, option buttons, ect.), click the bottom "carrot" style arrow to open a sub menu
3. Click "Set Control Defaults"

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in design view.

On the design tab of the ribbon, in the Controls group, click on the Text Box button, but - this is important - do not click on the form yet.

Activate the Property sheet. All properties you set now, will become the default for new text boxes on this form.

Activate the Format tab of the Property Sheet.

Scroll down.

Make sure that the Auto Label property is set to Yes (this is the default setting).

Change the LabelX property to 0.

Change the LabelY property to (for example) 0.75 cm or 0.3".

You can now click on the form to create a text box.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your ribbon to add set control defaults.

Comment: in Access 2016: Ribbon-File-Options-Customize ribbon-all commands-set control defaults

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34754204)