# How can i persistently set the default values for control elements in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I am using a Plugin for Version Control with gitlab. This Plugin exports a whole Database to Textfiles which can be commited to a git-repository. You can than build the Database from these Textfiles. I am very happy with this Plugin, but I have encountered an issue related to the build functionality.

When the Plugin builds the database from text, it creates a new database and creates all objects as described in the textfiles. It does however seem to use the default format values for the control elements and these default values are messed up (Buttons are always white) on the MS-Access Version of my partner 500km away.

Now changing the default style for a database is actually not that difficult as described here: [Change default style of MS Access elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18817120/10338858)

However setting the default values like this is not persistent. A new database on her machine always falls back to to White Buttons, wrecking the whole appearance. I therefore need to set this values permanently but I haven't found out, where I can do that.

If anyone knows, that would be a great help.

Edit1: I do use the PlugInn already on 2 different machines, my Worklaptop and my Desktop PC and exporting and building the database works fine with no issues regarding the theme.

I also checked my source files, regarding @PeterTheme suggestions about the UseTheme property and they are set to true, see the following example of a ControlButton

```vb
Begin CommandButton
            Width =1701
            Height =283
            FontSize =11
            FontWeight =400
            FontName ="Calibri"
            ForeThemeColorIndex =0
            ForeTint =75.0
            GridlineThemeColorIndex =1
            GridlineShade =65.0
            UseTheme =1
            Shape =1
            Gradient =12
            BackThemeColorIndex =4
            BackTint =60.0
            BorderLineStyle =0
            BorderThemeColorIndex =4
            BorderTint =60.0
            ThemeFontIndex =1
            HoverThemeColorIndex =4
            HoverTint =40.0
            PressedThemeColorIndex =4
            PressedShade =75.0
            HoverForeThemeColorIndex =0
            HoverForeTint =75.0
            PressedForeThemeColorIndex =0
            PressedForeTint =75.0
        End
```

However on my partners PC the useTheme is set to False after the rebuild. I suspect her System doesn't know what to do with the ColorIndex Properties. But even in a new database on her system the default Values are FFFFFF (white) on many of those.

The Plugin offers an "export Theme" Option, which i tried but didn't change anything. I also tried to export my Theme,sent it to her and let her import it. Also nothing.

Comment: This almost sounds like you are using both using Office themes but each are using different themes, which as far as I know are not saved with the database but are set under Options, General, Office Theme in Access.  Are you saying that when your partner restores this database and looks at the property sheet for a command button control that the property settings themselves are different than yours?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use the native, though undocumented, commands for this.

Apart from table *data*, they will write/read any object to/from a text file, for example a form:

```vb
SaveAsText acForm, "YourForm", "C:\Test\YourForm.txt"
LoadFromText acForm, "YourForm", "C:\Test\YourForm.txt"
```

These commands was meant to serve version control systems like *Visual SourceSafe*.

Comment: Thank you for you input. I am using this plugin https://github.com/joyfullservice/msaccess-vcs-integration which uses these functions. The issue is not within the plugin but rather the general settings on the different machines.

Comment: Oh, sounds like miss the theme. I'll check for how to transport that.

Comment: _Peter Cole_ has the tools for this, but his site is undergoing reconstruction, so no links. But you can study this presentation by him: [Show and Share: Themes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHycIvGhTSo&t=8s). Also, you may attend [DevCon 2022](https://www.donkarl.com/devcon/).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems with "Missing" Themes Access Databases, Word Documents, Excel Spreadsheets and Powerpoint presentations always contain a copy of the last Theme used.
That's part why a word docx that contains only a few characters is thousands of characters in size.

The problem you describe sounds like the "UseTheme" parameter is not being set = True   in the text file and hence the target database.

A textfile for a form created with "saveAsText" has sections for control defaults if any are different from the standard used by the Access version used while creating the form. From 2010 onwards the "useTheme" property is standard in accdb.
Further down the textile are sections for each control.

Comment: Thanks, you seem to be just the right person for this. I made some edits in the original post regarding you input.

Comment: To use themes you have to have an ACCDB or ACCDE and the Access version must be 2010 or above.  Version 2007 does not use Themes though you can have ACCDB. The difference is that 2010 has the hidden system table MSysResources that contains the Theme and any shared pictures. Opening a 2007 DB in 2010 creates the table and adds the default "Office Theme"